# Excel formula which Makes the Missed Characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been trying to make a formula where If `Col"C"` has 5 values and if some of the values are not available in Col"E" or that are missed,

then formula will take the number from Range(B7) and add the `Col"C"` values in `Col"E"` for those which are not available in `Col"E"`.

I just make below formula which is very simple and unable to make it as per desired output. Your help will be appreciated. If this thing is possible via code then please share the solution as well

```
=CONCATENATE($B$7," - ",C10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next formula:

```
=if(left(E7,10)<>$B$7,$B$7&" - "&C7,E7)
```

Place it on the 7th row and fill it down for the range you need.

You can place the above formula using VBA in this way:

```
Sub placeFormula()
  Range("E7:E11").Formula = "=if(left(E7,10)<>$B$7,$B$7&"" - ""&C7,E7)"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Mento: Glad I could help! I also edited the answer and placed a piece of code showing how the formula can be placed using VBA... Please, refresh the page (this one) to be sure you can see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again over this great help. thank you man.